# Do I have to downgrade Cocoapods for Xcode 9 (GoogleDataTransport-error)

Tags: xcode, firebase, compiler-errors, cocoapods

Hi I can't fix the error and  I rely on you guys. I had to update some pods and therefore I updated my CocoaPods since then I get the

[image: error]

I am wondering if it is because of my Xcode 9.2 and SDK 'iOS 11.2' but updating Xcode is not an option. I tried to delete pods, xcworkspace, Podfile, podfile.lock and delete /Users/XXXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData but it did not work...

[image: podfile]

any suggestions how I can fix the issue

Comment: Yes recent versions of Firebase require Xcode 10.  I'm not sure there's a version that supports both FirebaseFirestoreSwift and Xcode 9.

Comment: thanks a lot! Then I really have to update :-(